# TypeError: Widget.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'spec' Altair / Shapelets-platform

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, visualization, altair

I tried to work with Shapelets, I was trying the altair example but I got an issue with an argent:from shapelets.apps import DataApp it says that spec doens't exist, TypeError: Widget.**init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'spec'

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

app = DataApp(name=""altair example"")

# Define the data source
source = pd.DataFrame({'Horsepower': [130, 165, 150, 150, 140, 198],
                       'Miles_per_Gallon': [27.0, 28.0, 25.0, 25.0, 27.0, 17.0],
                       'Origin': ['USA', 'USA', 'USA', 'USA', 'USA', 'Europe'],
                       'Name': ['mazda rx4', 'mazda rx4 wag', 'datsun 710', 'hornet 4 drive', 'hornet sportabout', 'volvo 142e']})

# Define the Altair chart
spec = alt.Chart(source).mark_circle(size=60).encode(
    x='Horsepower',
    y='Miles_per_Gallon',
    color='Origin',
    tooltip=['Name', 'Origin', 'Horsepower', 'Miles_per_Gallon']
).interactive()

# Create the Altair chart component
altair_chart = app.altair_chart(title='Altair Chart 2', spec=spec)

# Add the chart to the app
app.place(altair_chart)

# Register the app
app.register()"
```

Can someone help me on this? I would be really grateful

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to use the chart, because the spec is not an argument for Shapelets. try this from shapelets.apps import DataApp

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

app = DataApp(name="altair example")

# Define the data source
source = pd.DataFrame({'Horsepower': [130, 165, 150, 150, 140, 198],
                       'Miles_per_Gallon': [27.0, 28.0, 25.0, 25.0, 27.0, 17.0],
                       'Origin': ['USA', 'USA', 'USA', 'USA', 'USA', 'Europe'],
                       'Name': ['mazda rx4', 'mazda rx4 wag', 'datsun 710', 'hornet 4 drive', 'hornet sportabout', 'volvo 142e']})

# Define the Altair chart
spec = alt.Chart(source).mark_circle(size=60).encode(
    x='Horsepower',
    y='Miles_per_Gallon',
    color='Origin',
    tooltip=['Name', 'Origin', 'Horsepower', 'Miles_per_Gallon']
).interactive()

# Create the Altair chart component
altair_chart = app.altair_chart(title='Altair Chart 2', chart = spec)

# Add the chart to the app
app.place(altair_chart)

# Register the app
app.register()
```

you can look at your documentation https://shapelets.io/doc/ https://github.com/shapelets/shapelets-demo